# How to programatically knows the size of NavigationBar and status bar

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

If only status bar shows up, the value is 20
If navigationBar shows up too the value is 64
If no status bar but with navigationBar the value is 44

I want to turn this into a code. Basically, rather than setting

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone
```

I want to just manually adjust inset of UIScrollView and put down view based on the number.

Unless you guys have better idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect navigationBarRect =self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
CGRect statusBarRect =[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
```

Comment: Be careful with this one... under some circumstances, at least, statusBarFrame will return a width of 20 and a height of 480.  I see this (at least) when first switching to landscape mode.  So if you only look at height to adjust your UI, things will end badly.

Comment: ohh...this situation is rarely or continuously ?

Answer (score 0):

Following way you can programmatically get frame of navigationbar :

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
```

For more reference : http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/